# Docker Compose: Apt-utils installation problem

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, apt-get

I am trying to build a new image in Docker Compose but the following problem occurs

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt-utils_2.4.7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: ]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y apt-utils' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Service 'nginx-service' failed to build : Build failed
```

In my Dockerfile I'm running: `RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils` and with `--fix-missing`.

None of the related questions or other solutions helped me and I've been stuck for quite a while. What am I missing?

Thanks!

EDIT: The whole Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y nginx 
RUN apt-get clean 
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Etc/UTC apt-get -y install tzdata
RUN apt-get install -y php php-xml php-curl php-fpm php-mysql 
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y php-zip --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y php-gd --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apt-get install -y nano
RUN apt-get install -y mc
RUN apt-get install -y systemctl
RUN systemctl start nginx.service
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your Dockerfile. If your Dockerfile is bloated with tons of other commands, copies, etc... related to your particular project, post a minimal one that anyone can copy/paste as is to reproduce the issue. Add as well all the steps folllowed o build your image. Note: the package uri on which you fail effectively returns a 404 error (hence does not exist...).

Comment: @Zeitounator just uploaded it

Comment: This Dockerfile is not using best practices. Chances are you run an install task based on an outdated apt index. Running your build with `--no-cache`  should fix the issue if I'm right.

Comment: my 2 cent: get some time to get familiar with the internals of docker to understand why 1) writting a `RUN` stanza for every action will produce fat images even if you (think you) are cleaning things arround 2) installing `systemctl` inside an image is anything but a good idea for images intended for production. In the mean time, you can use and customize the official `nginx:latest` and `php:8.1-fpm` inside a `docker-compose.yml` project to fulfill your requirement in a much better way IMO (and probably to get a better chance to learn from a better starting point).

Comment: It indeed created the image with `docker-compose build --no-cache`. Also thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building the image like this:
`docker-compose build --no-cache`
worked for me

Answer (score 3):

usually, when we are building a new image, we use update then install like this

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils
```

This will update apt source list and will make the package available to install.

Adding this to your `Dockerfile` should fix the issue.

If you want to install many at once you can add the packages like the following :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  bzr \
  cvs \
  git \
  mercurial \
  subversion \
```

Comment: Should I add `apt-get update` in front of every install? 
Note: You can now check the whole dockerfile

Comment: I will update my answer, you need to do it once.

Comment: please mark as accepted so it will help others.

Comment: Actually, this resolved the problem `docker-compose build --no-cache` for now. I appreciate your idea of adding multiple options on the same line

Comment: aha, great then. You can add your solution and mark it as accepted then.